# three-gltf-loader uvScaleMap.updateMatrix is not a function

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to load a gltf with three-gltf-loader.
But rendering every frame throws this error.

```
  23658 | 
  23659 | if ( uvScaleMap.matrixAutoUpdate === true ) {
  23660 | 
> 23661 |   uvScaleMap.updateMatrix();
  23662 | 
  23663 | }
  23664 |
```

I found uvScaleMap is a variable assigned THREE.Texture Object.
And according to the [document](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/textures/Texture), THREE.Texture must have a method 'updateMatrix'.
But THREE.Texture Object in uvScaleMap doesn't contain that method.

Is this a bug of three-gltf-loader?
Something went wrong when create a Texture Object?
Thanks

threejs 0.93.0
three-gltf-loader 1.93.0

Comment: I found this was a bug of three-gltf-loader.
I wrapped GLTFloader.js by myself and it worked fine.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by wrapped or give more information on the steps to your fix?